# "Object doesn't support this option" Error 445 in VB Code

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make this code work. It gives the runtime error. Any help on how to fix it will be much appreciated. I am putting this code together to retain the files for record retention and I am no that much of a programmer. Thank you.

The error is in the file search method.

```
  Option Explicit
    Sub PopulateDirectoryList()
'dimension variables
        Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject, objFolder As Folder
Dim objFile As File, strSourceFolder As String, x As Long, i As Long
Dim wbNew As Workbook, wsNew As Worksheet

ToggleStuff False 'turn of screenupdating

Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject  'set a new object in memory
strSourceFolder = BrowseForFolder 'call up the browse for folder routine
If strSourceFolder = "" Then Exit Sub

Workbooks.Add 'create a new workbook

Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsNew = wbNew.Sheets(1) 'set the worksheet
wsNew.Activate
'format a header
With wsNew.Range("A1:F1")
    .Value = Array("File", "Size", "Modified Date", "Last Accessed", "Created Date", "Full Path", "Size")
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 7
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Size = 12
End With

***With Application.FileSearch*** 'ERROR
    .LookIn = strSourceFolder  'look in the folder browsed to
   .FileType = msoFileTypeAllFiles 'get all files
    .SearchSubFolders = True  'search sub directories
    .Execute

 For x = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count 'for each file found, by the count (or index)
       i = x 'make the variable i = x
       If x > 60000 Then  'if there happens to be more than multipls of 60,000 files, then add a new sheet
          i = x - 60000  'set i to the right number for row placement below
          Set wsNew = wbNew.Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(wsNew.Index))
          With wsNew.Range("A1:F1")
            .Value = Array("File", "Parent Folder", "Full Path", "Modified Date", _
                                               "Last Accessed", "Size")
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 7
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Size = 12
           End With

       End If
        On Error GoTo Skip 'in the event of a permissions error

        Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(.FoundFiles(x)) 'set the object to get it's properties
         With wsNew.Cells(1, 1) 'populate the next row with the variable data
             .Offset(i, 0) = objFile.Name
             .Offset(i, 1) = Format(objFile.Size, "0,000") & " KB"
             .Offset(i, 2) = objFile.DateLastModified
             .Offset(i, 3) = objFile.DateLastAccessed
             .Offset(i, 4) = objFile.DateCreated
             .Offset(i, 5) = objFile.Path

         End With
          ' Next objFile
Skip:
'this is in case a Permission denied error comes up or an unforeseen error
'Do nothing, just go to next file
     Next x
wsNew.Columns("A:F").AutoFit

End With

'clear the variables
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set wsNew = Nothing
Set wbNew = Nothing

ToggleStuff True 'turn events back on
End Sub
Sub ToggleStuff(ByVal x As Boolean)
Application.ScreenUpdating = x
Application.EnableEvents = x
End Sub


Function BrowseForFolder(Optional OpenAt As Variant) As Variant
    '''Code from kpuls, www.VBAExpress.com..portion of Knowledge base submission

  Dim ShellApp As Object
  Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
    BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, OpenAt)

    On Error Resume Next
    BrowseForFolder = ShellApp.self.Path
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set ShellApp = Nothing

    Select Case Mid(BrowseForFolder, 2, 1)
        Case Is = ":"
            If Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = ":" Then GoTo Invalid
        Case Is = "\"
            If Not Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = "\" Then GoTo Invalid
        Case Else
            GoTo Invalid
        End Select
    Exit Function

Invalid:


ToggleStuff True
End Function
```

Comment: *where* is the runtime error?

Comment: Guess: You do not have a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime library. Select Tools then References. Is "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" near the top and ticked?  If not, scroll down and tick it.  Without it, "FileSystemObject" is undefined.

Comment: Another guess.  You are using a release later than 2007.  FileSearch was only available up to 2007.  See for example:  http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/643288-excel-2010-visual-basic-applications-replacement-application-filesearch.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get some help, you need to specify *where* you get the error. This time you've been lucky, I've recognized an error I went through some time ago.

### Cause of the error

```
With Application.FileSearch
```

### Error description

> Run-time error 445: Object doesn't support this option

### Cause

The method has been removed since > Excel 2003. In later versions, in fact, the method has just been removed because of stability-security reasons.

### Work-around

Someone (not me, I've just come through it for a replacement I quickly had to do) didn't accept this change and has developed some alternative functions to embed in you VBA project and keep on using an "almost-the-same" approach. There are several through the web (by simply browsing *alternative solutions to FileSearch after Excel 2003*, [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/643288-excel-2010-visual-basic-applications-replacement-application-filesearch.html#) you find the solution I've implemented successfully; clearly you need to adapt it to your code but this is the way to go if you want to keep on using your current approach.

Comment: Please, when you downvote an answer leave also a comment, especially if it works. It's not the first time over the last 24 hours and I'm starting to think about serial downvoting (also imagining the reason).

Comment: this answer shows a lot of effort, especially detecting what's causing error on OP's code, I also wonder why this got a downvote..

Comment: Thank you @Fev, I never think even a complex answer cannot get downvotes (there might be many reasons and I would be happy to learn them), but I was wondering because since yesterday it happened already on other of my answers and all this after a debate where another user and I were not agreeing on a behavioral thing ;)

Comment: @Fev and MatteoNNZ I assume this got a downvote because the question should be VTC for Unclear.  Some people don't like supporting quality answers to substandard questions (although there was winter hats and badges that reward people for doing so)

Comment: @Chrismas007 thank you, it might be that. I've personally got nothing against this (something against the serial downvoting, though), but I would just like a comment to be left :)

Answer (score 1):

, i think there is a solution for most of the apps and some very old game having this **error:run-time 445**, in windows 8 , or 10 architecture . credit goes to **Microsoft** , they had include a function in open menu while *right click on an app* you want to open, there is "**troubleshoot compatibility**" just run it .
***it helped me***, so may be it would help you too. 
its because of the software or games build in very old versions of VB, which are not supported by today's OS's.