# Searching a File in Directory

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to search a file in user-defined directory. My file structure like that `xxx__description__myFileName__YYMMDD.txt` there'll be multiple versions of this file so I want to list all files in directory which includes `myFileName` in their filename. Also I don't know is it the efficient way to list files with such type of code.

I tried to use this code but it gives me an error:

> Run-time error '445': Object doesn't support this action

```
Sub findFiles()
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim myFile As String

   myFileName = "ABC123"

   With Application.FileSearch
      .NewSearch
      .LookIn = "C:\myTestDirectory"
      .fileName = "*myFileName*.xlsx"
      .SearchSubFolders = True
      If .Execute() > 0 Then
         For i = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count
            Debug.Print .FoundFiles(i)
         Next i
      End If
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please tell which Excel version you use? Because `Application.FileSearch` doesn't exists anymore since Excel 2007

Comment: Should it be `"*myFileName*.xlsx"` or `"*myFileName*.txt"`? And check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28181734/8993210

Comment: @Peh 2013 i used sorry i just learned it thanks.

Comment: @Lisa should it be txt

Comment: @Hakan OK the issue is that `Application.FileSearch` does not exist anymore in Excel 2013, so that is why you get "*Object doesn't support this action*". To write a workaround see the link Lisa gave in her comment. This should solve your question. If not [edit] your question update your code and tell where you got stuck. Possible duplicate of ["Object doesn't support this option" Error 445 in VB Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179994/object-doesnt-support-this-option-error-445-in-vb-code)